# XPath string-join for text with markup

Tags: html, parsing, xpath

I have the HTML code looks like this:

```
<td>Known text and something <i>follows</i> or not</td>
<td>Unknown text <b>with some</b> subcontainer(s) or without it</td>
```

Lets say:

```
<td>Address line 1 <i>(office)</i> in <b>Dallas</b></td>
<td>1, Main Ave. <b>Dallas</b>, 123456</td>
```

In the above example the “Address line” is known text and “1” may follows or may not, or may be “2”, or “3”, etc., as well as contain HTML markup in ANY place, even before the known text. “1, Main Ave. Dallas, 123456” is unknown text and may contain some hypertext markup anywhere or may not.

So, I need to capture the whole string “1, Main Ave. Dallas, 123456” and I write the following XPath expression for Screaming Frog SEO Spider:

```
//td[starts-with(descendant-or-self::*/text(),'Address line')][1]/following-sibling::*[1]//descendant-or-self::*/text()
```

It successfully does its job except joining the output in one line. Guess I need to use **string-join** function but failed with syntax while I’m novice with XPath. Could somebody help please?

Comment: Try `string(//td[starts-with(., 'Address line')][1]/following-sibling::*[1])`

Comment: It doesn't work at least in Screaming Frog SEO Spider: "Invalid Custom Extraction Configured"